# Powershell Remoting always logs in as anonymous

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need some help in automating deploying some applications on my domain.  The deployment process follows this basic flow in a Powers Shell script:

1. Stop services
2. Copy out applications
3. Log into at least 1 remote server and run "\Services\Shipping\ShippingService.exe /deploy"
4. Start services.

I'd like to cut out step 3 and integrate it in my script.  What I've got so far is

```
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName ServerName -Credential:'domain\user' -Authentication Kerberos
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {
\Services\Shipping\ShippingService.exe /deploy
}
```

This is paired down to just 1 application, but there are actually 5.  The problem I have is that these applications use Integrated Security to access a Sql Server database so it fails with "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

How do I get my remote session to run as the domain\user specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into what is called a "Double Hop" Scenario. You are remoting into one machine and from there, accessing a remote share. This is possible using PowerShell but you have to use CredSSP authentication.

Comment: I saw the CredSSP in the documentation, but couldn't get it to work.  From my computer it kept telling me "CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration."  I thought I enabled it on the server, do I also need to enable it on my computer?

Comment: @Kleinux Yes you do need to enable the "client" role on your client machine as well as telling the server that it is the "server" role. Then when using invoke-command include -Authentication CredSSP